# Adding MS Access and Excel files inside NSIS Installer package

Tags: excel, installation, ms-office, nsis

I am creating an NSIS Installer package sample for a project I am working on. I need certain MS Access and Excel files to be automatically placed in the documents folder directory; "C:\User\MyName\Documents\PexApp\Storage", instead on my application having to connect to a network sharefolder to get the files. I want offline installation to be possible.

There are three excel files that are supposed to go to the PexApp folder and two Access database files that are supposed to go to the Storage folder inside the PexApp folder.

How do I add the files inside the installer package (if it is possible) so that they may be available for offline placement through the installer and what scripts or methods should I use or consider?

Answer (score 2):

```
OutFile "MySetup.exe"
Name "MySetup"
RequestExecutionLevel user

Section

SetOutPath "$DOCUMENTS\PexApp"
File "Excel1.xls"
File "Excel2.xls"
File "Excel3.xls"

SetOutPath "$DOCUMENTS\PexApp\Storage"
File "Access1.db"
File "Access2.db"

SectionEnd
```

Comment: How should the NSIS compiler know where to get the files so that it may place them within the "MySetup.exe" installer package? @Anders

Comment: You just specify the path in the File instruction: File "c:\myfiles\file.exe"